# flex mobile. how to back data?

Tags: apache-flex

I have 2 views.
 This is the 1-st view.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
        title="MTA">
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;

            import adobe.utils.CustomActions;

            import data.MTA_Item;

            [Bindable]
            public static var actions:ArrayCollection;
            public var firstItem:MTA_Item;
            public var secondItem:MTA_Item;
            public var thirdItem:MTA_Item;
            public function initItems():ArrayCollection
            {
                actions = new ArrayCollection();
                firstItem = new MTA_Item(1,"Test","Test note");
                secondItem = new MTA_Item(2,"DevCom","My First Notes");
                thirdItem = new MTA_Item(3,"Auto" , "BMW");
                actions.addItem(firstItem);
                actions.addItem(secondItem);
                actions.addItem(thirdItem);
                return actions;
            }
            override public function set data(value:Object):void
            {
                if(actions == null)
                initItems();
            }
        ]]>


    </fx:Script>

    <s:VGroup>

    <s:Label text="was" >

    </s:Label>
    </s:VGroup>
    <s:List id="items" left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0" dataProvider="{actions}" change="navigator.pushView(FormDetails, items.selectedItem)">
        <s:itemRenderer>
            <fx:Component>
                <s:IconItemRenderer label="ID:{data.ID}Name:{data.Name}" />
            </fx:Component>
        </s:itemRenderer>
    </s:List>

</s:View>
```

2-nd view.

```
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;

            import views.FlexMobileTestAppHomeView;
            public function list_changeHandler(event:Event):void
            {
                var name:String = _namechange.text;
                var notes:String  = _note.text;
                navigator.pushView(FlexMobileTestAppHomeView,data);

            }
            override public function set data(value:Object):void
            {

            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <s:navigationContent>
        <s:Button label="Back"
                  click="navigator.popToFirstView()"/>
    </s:navigationContent>
    <s:actionContent >
        <s:Button label="save" click="list_changeHandler(event)" />

    </s:actionContent>

    <s:HGroup verticalAlign="middle" gap="12">

        <s:VGroup>
            <s:HGroup>
                <s:Label text="Name:" />
                <s:TextInput  id="_namechange" text="{data.Name}">

                </s:TextInput>  
            </s:HGroup>
            <s:HGroup>
                <s:Label text="Notes:"/>
                <s:TextArea id="_note"  text="{data.Notes}" />


            </s:HGroup>

        </s:VGroup>

    </s:HGroup>

</s:View>
```

I need pass data to 2-nd.Then i must edit "name" , and "notes" and button save must return new data to 1-st view. How i can get "actions" from 1-st view and edit?

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of ways to share data between two components.   I wrote this blog post about the Flex facilities for [sharing data between two Flex Components](https://www.flextras.com/blog/index.cfm/2013/2/1/How-does-one-Flex-Component-talk-to-another-Flex-Component); however what I think you will be best suited with something more specific.

I'd look into these options:

1. Override the createReturnObject method in the second view.  [More information here](http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_Passing_Data_on_Pop_Methods_in_Mobile_Flex-18189.html).  Be sure to read the comments for information about accessing the data in recent Flex versions.
2. Use a framework that supports Dependency Injection.  RobotLegs and Swiz are two options I've used in the past.  Basically, create a model object that contains a reference to a selectedItem and inject that into both views.  Many would claim that this is the best way.
3. Store a reference to the selected object in a static variable; so that you can reference it in both views.  This is a lot less of a learning curve than number 1.
4. Since you are already passing a reference to the component in the `pushView` method; are you sure the reference isn't automatically updated when you go back?  Really both views are in essence using the same memory reference to get at the data.  You may have to refresh the list for the list to pick up on the changes, though.  Or I could be wrong on this one.